# Show full decimal in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decimal, rounding

I'd like to print the full decimal value of a number in Ruby. I have this:

```
number = 0.00000254
number.round(8)
puts "Your number equals: " + number.to_s
```

The number will always be a maximum of eight places after the decimal and I want to always show them all. However, the above code only returns this:

```
=> Your number = 0.0
```

(The rounding is only my attempt to get the decimal places that far, I have no desire to round the number). How can I force Ruby to show up to eight places even when there are zeroes at the end like if the number was .00000100?

I just started learning the language last week so if you could use the example above in your answer, that would be great.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Why would this generate an error? Am I not simply declaring a variable?
I'm using 1.9.3

Comment: Hmm, I just put into ruby "number = 1.2345" and then "puts number.to_s" and it printed just fine.

Comment: 1.2345 is fine.  It's the lack of a leading 0 that's a syntax error.  0.123 is okay, .123 not so much.

Comment: You are indeed correct. I had a zero in the code; didn't put it here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
number = 0.00000254

puts "%.8f" % number
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks. However, suppose I want to subtract two numbers, number1 and number2, both decimals the same style as above. I've tried putting them like this puts "%.8f" %(number1 - number2).to_s but it prints 0.00000000. How would I fix this?

Comment: if number1 and number2 are both 0.00000254, then it should be zero :)  Try it without the to_s though, that may help.

Comment: Oh, they're different numbers, I just meant that they were both eight decimal places long. I'll make a new question at some point, you've helped me enough for now, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`number_with_precision`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_with_precision) from ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelpe.

```
> include ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper
 => Object
> number_with_precision(0.00000254, precision: 8)
 => "0.00000254"
```